# Can I use the STLink on a Nucleo to program a 5V board

Tags: stm32, integrated-circuit, programming, debugging, st-link

I want to use the STLinkV2 on the nucleo board I have to program an external STM32f4, and I have the SWD pins connected according to section 6.2.4 in the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwib5ISWlZDwAhWB-J4KHSN5AIAQFjAMegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fuser_manual%2Fdm00452640-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1360-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0y7j1zrtGVnka7JFZNTuQZ).An earlier unsuccessful attempt to use an ftdi breakout didn't work, but the 5v Vdd could power the board. However, the STLink cannot since it's 3v3, so I need to power both boards.  I'm worried that when I power up the second board I may damage the programmer, since the STLink is 3v3, and Vdd on the target board is 5v. I know some of the pins are 5v tolerant, but I'm not sure which ones, and I don't know how to proceed. My current plan is to connect only ground and the data pins and leave Vdd separate, will this work?

Comment: I did this, and it worked

Comment: You can post your findings as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to program the target board by connecting only the data pins and ground. It seems sufficient to simply leave the two Vdd pin unconnected.